# highchart boost doesn't render correctly when going above y-max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts v6.0.1 and the boost module.

When rendering points larger than y-max then the line is rendered incorrectly (drawn below y-min).

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/co6q5u8b/1/)

If you change y-max to a higher value than point, the rendering is correct.

```
yAxis: {
  min : 0,
  max : 10, // <-- change to 100 and rendering is correct
},
```

Is this a bug ? Or am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug (you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues) but setting `useGPUTranslations` to true results in correct rendering.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.useGPUTranslations

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k3p29r35/

Comment: useGPUTranslations created a whole new range of issues for me. But setting the series type to line (instead of area) fixed the issues.